# URL based Datasource routing in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

i'm working on multi-tenant app using spring boot and spring data rest, so when the user enters the url `http://app/dbn_name`, the app should use the database specified in URL, all the databases are having the same schema, so the problem is to select the database depending on URL, also the process of adding a database should be done by the end user, so adding database should be done dynamically, for the moment i'm storing database access information in application.properties .

i've found a [solution](https://nobuco.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/shard-with-routing-data-source/), but it's old and not adapted to spring boot, is there any suggestions adapted to spring boot.

this is my AppConfig.java

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
        org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.geopro" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.geopro.repositories" })
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "com.geopro.entities" })
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class , RepositoryConfig.class }) //
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
         HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean factory = new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
         factory.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
         return factory;
    }
}
```

CORS filter:

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

        public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
                HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");

                response.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "ALLOW-FROM  http://localhost:1841/geopro/");//ALLOW-FROM  http://localhost:1841/geopro/
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With, Cache-Control");
                 chain.doFilter(req, res);

        }

        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

        public void destroy() {}

}
```

Comment: Then adapt it to spring boot... We developed a solution years ago (see [here](https://mdeinum.wordpress.com/2007/01/05/one-application-per-client-database/) which still works. Remember Spring Boot is still spring so what worked before still works.

Comment: i tried to adapt pure spring solution but i'm not spring guru, i've just started with spring boot, spring boot do several configurations by default, is there any simple solution for this problem, if not i'm stuck in how to set url filter

Comment: Just add the filter to the configuration... Not sure what is the problem with that.

Comment: can you gimme an example please ? i've searched but i didn't found a good doc

Comment: What is it you don't understand? Just add the filter as a `@Bean` nothing more nothing less, how to add filters, listeners and servlets is pretty clear documented in the Spring Boot documentation.